# WooCommerce Custom Fields through add_to_cart

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-fields

I have a site where a user can spell out their name and we create a framed picture using photos of each letter.  I created a variation product in woocommerce and added a custom field "Description" with value "variable"

I'd like to have the user click a link after spelling out their name and use

```
$woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id );
```

to add it to the cart.  The thing is, I need to attach the word they spelled out to the custom field "Description" that I made so we know what word they want spelled out.  Is their a way to do this dyanmically with the add_to_cart function?  I've googled like crazy and can't figure it out, not even sure if custom fields work this way.  I don't even see a field labeled "Description" on the product page even though I created that custom field.

Thanks for any and all suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Further to your query on how to register custom fields, Gerhard Potgieter has a useful post on creating Custom Product Fields at:

http://gerhardpotgieter.com/2013/09/17/woocommerce-custom-product-fields/

I have amended his code to have a Expected Delivery field in the Shipping tab.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if i understood you well, but here's something you can try.

First, you must edit the add_to_cart function signature so it can ALSO receive the new parameter.

```
public function add_to_cart( $product_id, $new_parameter,$quantity = 1, $variation_id = '', $variation = '', $cart_item_data = array() )
```

Here i put the $new_parameter as mandatory, but it's up to you.

Second, create the code that inputs the new value to the custom field. Normally you can use the [update_post_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta) function

```
update_post_meta($product_id,"description",$new_parameter); /* Considering that your custom field slug is "description" */
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, gonna give this a try!